# Position of SVG text wrong in generated PNG, but correct in the SVG itself

Tags: svg, letter-spacing

Look at this SVG file: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Matrix_representing_a_6-cube.svg

In the PNG generated on the page the gray numbers are in the wrong place - both positioning and spacing are wrong. But if you click on the image and look at the actual SVG, everything works as expected. If I look at the image with Ubuntu Image Viewer or Gimp the spacing is also broken.

I already tried text tags with x and y coordinates (`<text x="7" y="7">63</text>`), but on the desktop that did not help. This SVG is valid, by the way.

What can I do to render a correct image?

---

[On Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Sarang#Text_problem_in_File:Matrix_representing_a_6-cube.svg) I got the following hint:

> this is an extreme example for combination of [phab:T36947](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T36947) and [phab:T65703](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T65703) (which get fixed in the next Wikimedia update)

Answer (score 0):

The image was heavily scaled, and it seems that is not a good idea when it comes to text. Now the text size is determined only by the `font-size` property, and it works fine both on the Wikimedia page and on the desktop.